# The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid using variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the following function to convert my date output to a Unix Timestamp, however I am receiving the following error:

> The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 9, file "DateConversion")

Code:

```js
function convertDates(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for(n=0;n<values.length;++n){
    var cell = values[n][0];
    var cellNew = cell.replace("at ", " ");
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(cellNew);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(Number(n), 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're specifying 0 columns, change it to 1 or more. Also, what you're trying to accomplish with a getRange inside an Loop? It's mostly a bad decision, and rarely essential.

Comment: Why do you say its a bad decision? I am doing also using a getRange inside a loop to get a particular cell and set its value (basically to update an entire Row - except few of the columns).

Comment: @NiravZaveri There's a server to do the computing and one to save and display the data, as so, when you use a `getRange`, you make the server contact another server, which uses alot of resources, as so, you should do a `getRange` that allocates all the cells you're going to use, modify this range, then paste it again. In your case, get the entire row, modify it, then paste, it will be MUCH faster, by making only 2 inter-server calls.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when passing a 0 value as the column in GetRange. After doing some tests I am sure that the row and column values you pass to getRange starts from 1, not 0.

Here is my test code:

```
  var row = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  Logger.log("Row: " + row);
  var col = 0;
  var range = sheet.getRange(row+1, col+1, 1, 1);
  range.setValue(0);
```

[before the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVaJk.png)
[after the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE83k.png)

And in the logs, the value of row is logged:

```
[18-10-30 04:29:57:257 PDT] Row: 1
```

So in my case, if you want to access the cell at A2, you have to call getRange(2,1,1,1);

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertDates() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // row number where dates begin
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var datesR = s.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow +1);
  var dates = datesR.getValues();
  for(n = 0; n < dates.length; n++ ) {
    dates[n][0] = dates[n][0].toString().replace("at ", " ");
  }
  // replace dates with revised array
  datesR.setValues(dates);
}
```